# I want to prevent using a loop twice in twig symfony3

Tags: html, css, symfony, for-loop, twig

I've got a few images, and I want to make a carousel of that.
But I do not want to loop over the images twice.

Can this be done?

My code is:

```
<div id="main-slider">
    {% for image in images %}
        <img src="/images/{{ image.url }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="main-slider-nav">
    {% for image in images %}
        <img src="/images/{{ image.url }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

As you can see, the loop is in there now twice. Is there a nice way to not do this?

Comment: What is the problem with this? Depending on how often images changes, this can be cached nicely

Comment: I think the probleme with this, is the duplication of same code of  logic, even if the images can be cached nicely, I like Matteo answer

Comment: @pbenard That's exactly the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer, you can build a string with the dynamic values (the lists of image tag) then use in the container div, as example:

```
    {%set accumulator = '' %}

    {% for image in images %}
        {%set accumulator = accumulator ~ '<img src="/images/'~image.url~'"/>' %}
    {% endfor %}


<div id="main-slider">
 {{ accumulator|raw }}
</div>
<div id="main-slider-nav">
 {{ accumulator|raw }}
</div>
```

Here a working [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ukl0bb) sample

Hope this help

Comment: With {% set foo%} mycontent {% endset %} https://twigfiddle.com/ukl0bb/2

Comment: If image names can come from your users, just take care about the `|raw` filter that drops escaping, thus opens an XSS breach. In that case, prefer using [`|purify`](https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle).

Comment: I'm going to use @pbenard 's answer. With the set. It's a little nicer! But thanks Matteo

Comment: no, use @pbenard's code that does't require to use `|raw` :)

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer or specify a new one with the complete solutiond